# UITableViewCell textLabel not changing the font with setAdjustsFontSizeToFitWidth in iphone

Tags: objective-c

I want to adjust the UITableViewCell's label font so i have used the following code:

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ItemCell";
UITableViewCell *cell = nil;
if (cell == nil) 
{
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc]
             initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1
             reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
}
if ( indexPath.section == 0 ) 
{
    NDOrderItem *item = [self.order.items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    //[cell.textLabel setMinimumFontSize:10];
    //[cell.textLabel setAdjustsFontSizeToFitWidth:YES];
    cell.textLabel.text = item.name;
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",item.quantity];
}
```

but the setAdjustsFontSizeToFitWidth is not adjusting the font of the textLabel.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the following line under viewDidAppear

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{ 
    self.title = @"Table Of Content";
    //
    // set row hight for your tableView 
    tableView.rowHeight = 30;
}
```